# Mongodb: Not expected result from aggregate ($lookup)

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup, ref

I´m looking for some help.

I have a collection called 'business' where I have objects like this:

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("5aefa97166763d28fc984c7a"),
    "name": "Business 1",
    "boxes": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5ac6bb69f3c36e17f0d34bd2")
        }
    ]
}]
```

There is another collection called boxes which has objects like:

```
[{
    _id: ObjectId("5ac6bb69f3c36e17f0d34bd2"),
    name:"Box1",
    color:"blue"
}]
```

The idea here is that there are businesses that own boxes and I want to keep both collection separated.

That said, I would like to retrieve this result:

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("5aefa97166763d28fc984c7a"),
    "name": "Business 1",
    "boxes": [{
        _id: ObjectId("5ac6bb69f3c36e17f0d34bd2"),
        name:"Box1",
        color:"blue"
    }]
}]
```

But I am getting this result:

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("5aefa97166763d28fc984c7a"),
    "name": "Business 1",
    "boxes": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5ac6bb69f3c36e17f0d34bd2")
        }
    ]
}]
```

Using $lookup as you can see below:

```
db.db('database').collection("business").aggregate({
    $lookup:{
        from: "boxes",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "box"
    },
    "$unwind": "$boxes" 
    }).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        res.send(result);
        db.close();
        res.end();
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all!

Comment: `localField: 'boxes._id'` you're pointing at the wrong path. Also you don't need the `$unwind` for your desired result and can simply use `as: 'boxes'` to overwrite the array of `ObjectId` values with your foreign collection matches. And `$unwind` is a separate document in the pipeline anyway, but just remove the line as it's currently incorrect syntax and not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```
db.business.aggregate([{$lookup:{from: "boxes", localField: "boxes._id", foreignField: "_id", as: "box" }},{"$project":{"_id":1,"name":1,"boxes":"$box"}}])
```

The lookup creates an array "box" which has all matching documents from the boxes collection.The next stage in the pipeline, $project , selects _id and name from the new document and renames the box array to boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If You have multiple objectIds and need in one array Boxes:

```
Ex: "boxes": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5ac6bb69f3c36e17f0d34bd2")
        },
       {
            "_id": ObjectId("5ac6bb69f3c36e17f0d34bd3")
        }
    ]
```

Then u need to do **group**

**Query :**

```
db.getCollection('business').aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$boxes"} ,
    {$lookup:{
        from: "boxes",
        localField: "boxes._id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "box"
    }},
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        name: { $first: '$name' },
        boxes: { 
           $push: {
                  _id: '$boxes._id',
                  name: '$boxes.name'
                   color: '$boxes.color'
                 } 
              }
       }
    }

])
```